# Debugging Google Visualization Chart -- Callback being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, callback, google-visualization

I need my chart to animate when it's in view. The chart keeps repeating the first piece of data -- multiple callback? and then it runs through the rest of the data after five times of running through the 2001, 13341

```
$(allInView);
$(window).scroll(allInView);
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}



    function allInView() {
    google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function () {
        var rawData = [
          ['2001', 13341],
          ['2009', 28334],
          ['2009', 423686]
        ];
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
          "cols": [
            {"id":"","label":"Year","type":"string"},
            {"id":"","label":"Revenue","type":"number"}
          ]
        });
        var options = {
            hAxis: {textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},  viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 4}},  
            vAxis: { baseline:0, baselineColor: '#FFF', gridlineColor: '#FFF',  textStyle:{color: '#FFF'}, viewWindow: {min: 0,max: 800000} },
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            colors: ['#FFF'],
            textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},
            pointSize: 10,
            series: {
                0: { pointShape: 'square'}
            },
            pointSize: 4,
            lineWidth: 3,
            animation:{
            startup: true,
            duration: 300,
            easing: 'linear'
          }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        drawChart();
        setInterval(drawChart, 1000);
        var rowIndex = 0;
        function drawChart() {
          if (rowIndex < rawData.length) {
            data.addRow(rawData[rowIndex++]);
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        }
      },
      packages:['corechart']
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error in the code from the question

`var options` has 1 too many closing brackets

also, needed to include `animation` options

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var rawData = [
      ['2007', 132321],
      ['2023', 245454],
      ['2043', 623436]
    ];
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Year","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Followers","type":"number"}
      ]
    });
    var options = {
      animation: {
        startup: true,
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'in'
      },
      backgroundColor: 'cyan',
      legend: {position: 'none'},
      colors: ['#FFF'],
      textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, 1000);
    var rowIndex = 0;
    function drawChart() {
      if (rowIndex < rawData.length) {
        data.addRow(rawData[rowIndex++]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    }
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it to play when the the div #curve_chart is in view? rather than having it play automatically?

Comment: of course, is your function `allInView` called when this is the case? probably need to see more code but recommend loading google first, before anything else, the `callback` will let you know not only when google is ready, but the page as well -- then draw the chart(s) in `allInView`

Comment: I've done that except when I move to another section and back to the section where the div is, it looks like it's being called endlessly...the bar for the first piece of data goes up and down like 5 times before it runs through the actual data? Any fixes?

Comment: would need to see all the code, are you clearing the interval at some point?

Comment: I'll re-edit my post so you can see the entire code, I tried clearing the interval, but must have done it wrong because it didn't work